# only highlighted items in a loop

Tags: command-line, files

I can write a little loop in Ubuntu 20.04 terminal that will act against several files, such as this command line:

for x in z1*.png; do ext="${x:2}"; extnew="${ext%.png}.jpg";  ffmpeg -i "$x" -vf scale="iw/1:ih/1" "$extnew"; rm -f "$x"; done

However, what I would like to do is to have a loop like this that will act against the currently highlighted/visually selected files in the Nautilus (Gnome Files) folder from which I opened the terminal window.  Is that possible from Terminal?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? What Ubuntu desktop are you using (standard Ubuntu desktop or Xubuntu, Kubuntu...?) Please "edit" your question, add that information and format the command with code formatting to improve clarity of your question.

Comment: What do you mean "highlighted"? Is it files that you have selected in Nautilus (Gnome Files)? Please elaborate in your question.